# How to make GML / JTS Geometry valid in Java?

Tags: java, geospatial, spatial, jts

I am using the JTS library for manipulating with some Geometry objects that arise from GML files. Some of the Geometry objects that I obtain are (however) invalid. I recall that the .NET class SqlGeometry has a MakeValid method for this purpose. Similarly, I know that PostGIS and many relational databases (like PostgreSQL and SQL Server) have built-in functionality for validating GMLs or Geometry structures. Sadly I have not been able to find any equivalent functionality in JTS or in the Java world in general. The closest thing I came across was the `Geometry#buffer()` method (from JTS) with `0` as an argument, but it does not seem to solve my problem.
Does anyone know a proper MakeValid functionality in some Java library?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately JTS does not yet have a MakeValid equivalent.  Hopefully that can be contributed at some point.  For now `buffer(0)` is the best option, although it can have issues with "figure-8" polygons.

Comment: See also this JTS [issue](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/issues/87), which has a link to an external implementation that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do you know an alternative to JTS which can either validate GML or a Geometry object?